# New to c++ getting an error when I try to compile

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

so I'm completely new to programming and I'm taking a course in College and it's over c++, but it doesn't teach basics. Apparently I should have had some prior knowledge on the subject, but that wasn't told to me. Anyways, I'm trying to copy this code from the book to see what happens and I can't get it to compile. 
I'm using Notepad++ on my Mac.

### Heres the code, it's not too long, so hopefully it's okay that I paste it here.

```
int main()
{
    int a = 20000;
    char c = a;
    int b = c;
    if (a != b)
        cout << "Oops!: " <<a<< "!=" <<b<< "\n";
    else
        cout << "Wow! We have large characters\n";
}
```

---

Then when I go to compile it in terminal, I get this error.

---

```
dhcp-10-202-146-180:programs Admin$ g++ unsafe_conversions.cpp
unsafe_conversions.cpp:7:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'cout'
                cout << "Oops!: " <<a<< "!=" <<b<< '\n';
                ^
unsafe_conversions.cpp:9:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'cout'
                cout << "Wow! We have large characters\n";
                ^
2 errors generated.
```

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as this is all greek to me at the moment.

Comment: `#include <iostream>` and call it `std::cout`.

Comment: _Any help would be greatly appreciated_ Try searching here on Stack Overflow, there's many duplicate posts. Also, the next time you post a question, please try to come up with a more descriptive title. See [ask] for advice on how to write good questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the comments in the code below.  The compiler needs to know that `cout` is part of the standard library (`std`), and it needs access to the header file that defines it (`iostream`).

```
#include<iostream>                                   
// include the iostream header from the standard library (that contains std::cout)

int main()
{
    int a = 20000;
    char c = a;
    int b = c;
    if (a != b)
    {
        //use std::cout as it comes from the std library
        std::cout << "Oops!: " <<a<< "!=" <<b<< "\n";  
    }
    else
    {
        //use std::cout as it comes from the std library
        std::cout << "Wow! We have large characters\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so firstly thank you for the help. I really appreciate it.

Secondly, is there a reason you added those braces after the if and else statement?

Thirdly, it compiled!This is what I get 

Oops!: 20000!=32

My question is where is it getting 32 from and why isn't it returning the else statement? Shouldn't a = b based on the code?

Comment: First question: I have added braces as it's just coding practice and second is : char size is 1 byte which is 256 bit.So it can store value update 0-256. if you assign more than 256 it will start again 0. So if you  take modules operator 20000%256 you will get 32 value

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/) is a link for a tutorial. You can learn a few basics here. As for your code, you need to include a statement `#include <iostream>`. It is a header file which includes the definition for `cout<<` cout displays a stream of characters on screen. Your code basically compares the ascii values of character c and integer a. Also you need to include this statement `using namespace std;`